# How can you determine if a function return value is a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the yield return a collections.Iterable but many types are also iterable

```
def aaaa():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3 

d = aaaa()

print(d,type(d),isinstance(d, collections.Iterable))
```

the print type

```
<generator object aaaa at 0x0000000002626B88> <class 'generator'> True
```

i didn't find the class 'generator' or i can't do typecheck.

Comment: Why do you need to know?  The whole point of iterators and generators is you can iterate over it without needing to know what it is.

Comment: type checks are a code smell, avoid.

Comment: @BrenBarn: IF you need to iterate twice or more on the result you must know. You could just always use `itertools.tee` but that's an overhead you might only want to pay for generators. Even if 99.9% of all users don't need to know, there's always a few for which such a question is interesting. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to check if the *iterable* is a generator object:

```
import types
isinstance(aaaa(), types.GeneratorType) # ==> True
```

If you want to check if the *function* contains `yield` statements (i.e. the function is a generator):

```
import inspect
inspect.isgeneratorfunction(aaaa) # ==> True
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the inspect module, and in particular [inspect.isgeneratorfunction](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgeneratorfunction).

That said, the more interesting question is whether it's a list or other iterable. To answer that question, you can just check if `__getitem__` is defined on it.